# How may I set an environment variable to the quantity of unique lines in a set of text files?

Tags: cmd

How may I set an environment variable to the quantity of unique lines in a set of text files?The file set is all files matching a pattern e.g. *.m3u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "count=0"
    set "last=|"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type *.m3u 2^>nul ^| sort') do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!last!") do (
            endlocal & if not "%%~a"=="%%~b" ( set /a "count+=1" & set "last=%%~a" )
        )
    )
    echo %count% unique lines
```

Type all the lines, sort them and for each one, if it is not equal to the previous one, increment counter